# HTML mistake in meta or in link text

Tags: html

My website (with subsites, obviously) has a working head; one subsite somehow doesn't accept this `<head>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC><html lang="de" target="_blank"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" lang="de" target="_blank" charset="utf-8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" type="text/css">
<title>Some title</title>-->
</head><body><!--
<h1>Some living people</h1>
The people:<ul>
<li><a target="_blank" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People">The People</a><br>
wears the <a target="_blank" href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_the_Companions_of_Honour">Order of the Companions of Honour</a>  and the <a target="_blank" href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_the_British_Empire">Order of the British Empire</a><br>
wears something else<br>
some other text</li>
<li>someone else<br>
also more than one line</li>
</ul>
<h2>Some sayings</h2>
<p>saying 1</p>
<p>saying 2</p>
<p>saying 3</p>-->
</body></html>
```

When I open the file stored locally in a browser, it works fine. When uploading it to my server and requesting the URL of the page, I get the plain `html` code, which appears as in a `*.txt` file.

After deleting the following line the page also works well. When I replace `Order of the Companions of Honour` and `Order of the British Empire` with `a` and `b`, it doesn't make any trouble. But that's not what it's supposed to be. And I just can't find the actual error...

```
wears the <a target="_blank" href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_the_Companions_of_Honour">Order of the Companions of Honour</a> and the <a target="_blank" href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_the_British_Empire">Order of the British Empire</a><br>
```

Comment: Browsers use the content-type HTTP header (Not the metadata in the HTML document itself) to determine how a file is to be processed (e.g. as HTML, plain text, a PDF, etc). It is hard to see how deleting a line of HTML (especially inside a comment) would have any effect on that. Perhaps you have some server-side code which has a heuristic approach to determining the content-type header you are sending. We can't see it.

Comment: @Quentin Unfortunately, I have only limited access to the server, which isn't fully mine. I just have some disk space on it which I can fill with my files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see, the `<a>`troubling word`</a>` is "the". I got that behaviour with another site, which isn't (on a code basis) related to the one above.

The site works with the first version of everything before `<body>`, keeping the above in mind.